# Optimize too many if else condition

Tags: php, if-statement, optimization, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I know many question like this and or can use switch , but my code is different and i am begginer in php.

My if elseif  code :

```
<?php if (get_field('num_field') == '1'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link1'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link1'); ?></a></li>
<?php elseif (get_field('num_field') == '2'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link1'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link1'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link2'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link2'); ?></a></li>
<?php elseif (get_field('num_field') == '3'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link1'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link1'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link2'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link2'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link3'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link3'); ?></a></li>
<?php elseif (get_field('num_field') == '4'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link1'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link1'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link2'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link2'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link3'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link3'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link4'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link4'); ?></a></li>
<?php elseif (get_field('num_field') == '5'): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link1'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link1'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link2'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link2'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link3'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link3'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link4'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link4'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link5'); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link5'); ?></a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How Optimize this code ?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably gonna get shitstorm for posting a question that belongs to code review..

Comment: Does your code work like it's written now? If so, your question is off-topic here and should be asked at [codereview.se]. If it does *not* work as written now, then [edit] your question, explain what the code is supposed to do and how it's not working as expected, and ask a specific question related to the code.

Comment: "_How Optimize this code?_" is certanly off-topic here, but there are many users that feels they can break SO rules when they want, encouraging further such questions.

Comment: sorry all , Ok  i did know that

Comment: Good job @Barmar. Answering an off-topic question (that breaks the SO rules) it's the best way to encourage all users to make the same, posting many more off-topic questions in the SO sea full of duplicates, malformed, off-topic, unclear (and more...) questions. PS: it's not the first time I see you and many other users with very hight reputation that putting much effort to get worse the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
<?php
$end = get_field('num_field');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $end; $i++) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link' . $i); ?>"><?php the_field('dl_link' . $i); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = get_field('num_field');
if($a => 1 && $a <= 5) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= $a; $i++) {
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_field('dl_link'.$i); ?>"><?php the_field('t_dl_link'.$i); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$num_field = get_field('num_field');

for($i=1; $i < $num_field; $i++) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.the_field('dl_link'.$i).'">'.the_field('t_dl_link'.$i).'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: Because the accepted answer is so full of explanation. Go for it and delete it then.